# How do I use postsharp logging to write to applicationInsights? and How do I test that the logs are being written to application Insights?

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, postsharp, log4postsharp

I was trying to use application Insights as my logging backend from postsharp references. I have setup the application insights and was able to see live metrics. But I am not quite sure if postsharp logging alone is able to write to application insights.

**My code in Program.cs**

using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;

using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Backends.ApplicationInsights;

LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = new
ApplicationInsightsLoggingBackend("InstrumentationKey");

**GlobalAspects.cs file:**

using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;

using PostSharp.Extensibility;

// This file contains registration of aspects that are applied to several classes of this project.

[assembly: Log(AttributeTargetTypeAttributes=MulticastAttributes.Public, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes=MulticastAttributes.Public)]

Do I need to setup anyhting in my program.cs in order to completely make use of postsharp logging to write to applicationinsights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the default verbosity of the Application Insights logging backend to Trace to get the method call log records.

```
LoggingServices.DefaultBackend.DefaultVerbosity.SetMinimalLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
```

Comment: Thankyou. Can I filter out only certain logs?  I don't want to log everything like validation messages or anything like that.
Like What if I wanted to log only exceptions and errors? @AntoninProchazka

Comment: Is there any kind of reference on github or elsewhere for a complete only Postsharp Logging (without serilog) using only ApplicationInsights as backendsink that logs exceptions and information messages.#Postsharp

Comment: There are several options:
1) Set the log level to Info. (https://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_patterns_diagnostics_loglevel)
2) Make the LogAttribute multicast more specific. (https://doc.postsharp.net/multicast-conceptual)
3) Use different logging profiles. (https://doc.postsharp.net/logging-customizing#buildtime)

Comment: There's no such example now, but for better understanding, the ApplicationInsightsLoggingBackend passes all log records to Application Insights as TraceTelemetry. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.tracetelemetry?view=azure-dotnet)